# Cross-compile for linux on windows

Tags: windows, linux, cross-compiling

I've found little info about cross-compiling Linux binaries in Windows, most questions are about the opposite situation.

Has someone any experience or pointers to share?

I'd prefer Mingw over Cygwin, if I can choose.

Assume that the specific Linux target is available: I have the include headers and binaries.

Comment: See the top answer to [this question][1].  They use Cygwin though.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769968/c-cross-compiler-from-windows-to-linux/

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done this myself, but have you considered setting up a virtual machine, and compiling on that?  You could use a "network" share, so that both the Windows system and Linux virtual system can see the same directories.  With the Virtual Machine solution, it becomes much easier to target specific distributions and architectures.

Best of luck, regardless.

Comment: Doubtful that this is what he wants. He doesn't want to do Cygwin if possible, so I doubt a VM is wanted.