# How to fix certificate errors when using curl?

Tags: bash, curl, cygwin, gcutil

When I attempt to download from dl.google.com I receive this error :

```
ERROR: The certificate of `dl.google.com' is not trusted.
ERROR: The certificate of `dl.google.com' hasn't got a known issuer.
```

Here is entire command output

```
$ curl https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/release/install_google_cloud_sdk.bash
| bash
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  3607  100  3607    0     0   2820      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--  3125
bash: line 77: [: Files: binary operator expected
wget -O - https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/release/google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz > tm
p.4wwaU246zk/google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz
--2013-12-12 11:05:41--  https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/release/google-cloud-
sdk.tar.gz
Resolving my.proxy.com my.proxy.com)... x.x.x.x
Connecting to my.proxy.com (my.proxy.com)|x.x.x.x|:1234... conne
cted.
ERROR: The certificate of `dl.google.com' is not trusted.
ERROR: The certificate of `dl.google.com' hasn't got a known issuer.
```

Reading this question : [How do I fix certificate errors when running wget on an HTTPS URL in Cygwin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9224298/how-do-i-fix-certificate-errors-when-running-wget-on-an-https-url-in-cygwin) an option is to 
"add the --no-check-certificate option on the wget command-line" but since I'm using curl instead of wget is there a similar option for above command ?

Update : I've tried

```
curl -k https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/release/install_google_cloud_sdk.ba
sh | bash
```

But same error, could the proxy/firewall be blocking the connection ?

Answer (score 2):

**Original Answer**:

You are searching for `-k` or (long)  `--insecure` .. The man page is your friend ;) :

> -k, --insecure
>               (SSL)  This  option  explicitly allows curl to perform "insecure" SSL connections and transfers.
>                 All SSL connections are attempted to be made secure by using the CA certificate bundle installed
>                 by default. This makes all connections considered "insecure" fail unless -k, --insecure is used.
>                 See this online resource for further details: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

**Edit after update the question:**

You showed that you are already using the `-k` option here. I had a deeper look into your code and the task to be done:

You are trying to download a shell script from google servers. They **will** have trusted certificate, means you need to remove the `-k` as it is insecure (like the name).

After download you piping the script directly to `bash`. So the first question is: Did the download of the script succeed? (Can you post the script to some pastebin, in order to make it possible to verify this for me?) Will go on explaining after this questions have been answered

Comment: thanks, please see question update. Could the proxy/firewall be blocking the connection ?

Comment: Ok, I see your update. This has nothing to do with a firewall. It is a problem with the install script. **I would remove the `-k` in that example for security reasons**

Comment: "I would remove the -k in that example for security reasons" do you mind elaborating on the "security reasons" ?