# wget rejects the site's SSL certificate

Tags: ssl, https, debian, wget

So I accidentally stumbled upon this error on my server while debugging.

When I request an API url via wget with `wget https://example.com/`, I get the
`The certificate of «example.com» is not trusted.` (The URL is, of course, different)

I did a quick search for a solution and found [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9224298/how-do-i-fix-certificate-errors-when-running-wget-on-an-https-url-in-cygwin).

The `ca-certificates` package was already installed. I've ran `update-ca-certificates` and got the following:

```
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs... 0 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d....done.
```

I also ran `c_rehash`, which did add several missing links, but didn't change the outcome.

I checked the server's certificate via https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ and it passes with flying colors (gives an A+ grade, the certificate issuer is listed as COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA). Also, requesting the same document via PHP on the same server works fine.

I also tried explicitly setting `--ca-directory=/etc/ssl/certs` parameter for wget, but the result is the same.

I have no idea how to troubleshoot this issue further and I'm afraid it might cause issues in the future.

I'm running Debian 7.9 with OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013.

Comment: My guess is that it is related to the problem with multiple trust path I've described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27804710/python-urllib2-ssl-error/27826829#27826829. But to be sure one would need to know the exact hostname.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, you mean the hostname of the server which causes an issue with wget, right?

Comment: Yes, I mean the hostname so one can reproduce the problem and look deeper into it.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. My site worked fine in a browser and got a passing grade from www.ssllabs.com but `wget` would error out complaining of an invalid certificate.

The issue is that the "COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA" intermediate certificate is signed by multiple certificates (as [Steffen Ullrich](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3081018/steffen-ullrich) alluded to) one of which is included in more trust stores than the other.

Some OSs do not by default trust the "COMODO RSA Certification Authority" self-signed certificate even though it is trusted by most web browsers. The "AddTrust External CA Root" certificate, however, is trusted by most OSs.

Make sure you have not just the "COMODO RSA Certification Authority" certificate chain correct but that the "AddTrust External CA Root" chain is also correct.

If www.slllabs.com reports "Chain issues: None" then your `wget` shouldn't give you any certificate errors.

[image: example showing multiple certificate signing paths]

Answer (score -3):

You can use "--no-check-certificate" parameter on wget to avoid the check

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem, though, and I don't need a workaround