# Error when installing crosstool-ng on cygwin (_libintl_gettext)

Tags: c++, linux, cygwin

I have a problem with installing crosstool-ng on cygwin.

I have downloaded last package [here](http://crosstool-ng.org/download/crosstool-ng/) to root cygwin folder, then:

1. ./configure ALL OK
2. make - error!

Complete error log:

```
$ make
  SED    'ct-ng'
  SED    'scripts/crosstool-NG.sh'
  SED    'scripts/saveSample.sh'
  SED    'scripts/showTuple.sh'
  GEN    'config/configure.in'
  GEN    'paths.mk'
  GEN    'paths.sh'
  LD     'conf'
zconf.tab.o:zconf.tab.c:(.text+0x1799): undefined reference to `_libintl_gettext'
zconf.tab.o:zconf.tab.c:(.text+0x48f8): undefined reference to `_libintl_gettext'
zconf.tab.o:zconf.tab.c:(.text+0x592b): undefined reference to `_libintl_gettext'
zconf.tab.o:zconf.tab.c:(.text+0x5b20): undefined reference to `_libintl_gettext'
zconf.tab.o:zconf.tab.c:(.text+0xcd60): undefined reference to `_libintl_gettext'
zconf.tab.o:zconf.tab.c:(.text+0xcd6e): more undefined references to `_libintl_gettext' follow
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: zconf.tab.o: bad reloc address 0x564 in section `.data'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: final link failed: Invalid operation
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:108: recipe for target `conf' failed
make[2]: *** [conf] Error 1
Makefile:160: recipe for target `build-lib-kconfig' failed
make[1]: *** [build-lib-kconfig] Error 2
Makefile:120: recipe for target `build' failed
make: *** [build] Error 2
```

How can i fix it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might try the patch here: http://sourceware.org/ml/crossgcc/2012-05/msg00012.html