# Coding for Linux under Windows?

Tags: python, linux, fpga

i am using SoC FPGA+ARM A9 system. The ARM A9  will run Linux Yocto.
 I want to write some  software for  this Linux  on C or Python language. My question is, do i need to install  Linux on my Windows desktop in order to develop  software for Linux, or is there some kind of Linux Shell/emulator,  in which i can test my  code under Windows 7?

Comment: Python should be fairly portable.  But if you want to be absolutely sure you could run it in a Linux Virtual Machine or a Linux Container.

Comment: If you want to write C code, you don't just need a linux emulator, you need an ARM emulator, which is a much bigger issue. (And a cross-compiler, but that's easier.)

Comment: One in-between idea that might be worth considering: Install [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com), which gives you most of a GNU/Linux userland on Windows, including a build of Python that has all the Unix-specific stuff instead of the Windows-specific stuff (and a Unix-like C standard library, if you're serious about going that way).

Answer (score 2):

Python code is fairly portable as long as you don't use [Windows specific modules](https://docs.python.org/2/library/windows.html) or functions. And as  abarnert rightly mentions, some functions act differently on different operating systems. And not all functions are available on all platforms. But this is generally mentioned in the documentation.

You could [set up a cross-compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769968/c-cross-compiler-from-windows-to-linux) for Linux on Windows, but it is more ofter done the other way around, because Linux in general comes with more developer tools and has better infrastructure for installing software packages.

What you could do is set up a virtual machine (like [virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/), [vmware](http://www.vmware.com/) or [qemu](http://qemu.weilnetz.de/)) running Linux. That will enable you to get experience with Linux and its development tools.

If you are using an Altera board, it seems that their tools (Board Support Package) only run on Linux.

Comment: One minor quibble: It's not just Windows-specific modules; some cross-platform modules have Windows-specific functions (like `os.startfile`), or functions that act differently in Windows and Unix (like `os.rename`). Fortunately, every such case is clearly documented.

Comment: @abarnert Good point. I've updated the answer to take that into account.

Comment: Thank you very much.  Yes, i am using Altera DE1 SOC board. I will mainly use  LINUx on ARM  to  plot/visualize data. I will try virtual machine first, else i will install complete Ubuntu on my desktop system ( i just afraid that installing Linux will ruin  my  Windows  system, which will be catastrophic).

Comment: @user3597998 There are several guides on the internet about installing Linux next to Windows. And as long as you have a proper backup of your Windows system, the risk is low. If you've never made a backup, I suggest you do that *now*.