# running project on linux-build it on windows

Tags: linux, windows, cygwin, cross-platform

I am new to building a project (C++) on windows (generating .dll etc). My project was initially intended to run on Linux but the new requirements are to make it run on windows. I installed cygwin with base, devel packages and finally built the pre-requisite libraries but I am lost when it comes to building my project in cross-platform. How can this be done? what should be changed/included in a linux project to build and run it on windows?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769968/c-cross-compiler-from-windows-to-linux