# C++ compiler for Linux on Windows?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, cross-compiling

I'm fully aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769968/c-cross-compiler-from-windows-to-linux) asking for the same thing. That question is closed and rather old. Accepted answer suggests rather complicated way of *making your own cross-compiler* and it requires cygwin.

Maybe now there are some other, simpler ways of doing this?

Comment: A Linux VM? Get any and all the tools you need, straight out of the distro repositories.

Comment: @BoBTFish even if my target is ARM Linux? Something like RPi?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there is.
If you want cross-compile for linux on ARM, you can use [linaro toolchain](http://www.linaro.org/downloads/), which is available for windows. It doesn't require cygwin.

If you want cross-compile for linux on x86, that's a bit of a problem. The only ready-to-use toolchain (apart pre-built solution in that [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4770417/1823524)) that I'm aware of is "cross-compile tools" for Intel Edison ([here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/iot/hardware/edison/downloads)). There are some drawbacks to it:

1. It will compile 32-bit linux binary
2. Version for windows 64-bit requires cygwin
3. Version for Windows 32-bit doesn't require cygwin but contains case-sensitive filenames (i.e. there are some files with names that differ only in case and windows will consider them the same file). You may have to [make your Windows case-sensitive](https://superuser.com/questions/266110/how-do-you-make-windows-7-fully-case-sensitive-with-respect-to-the-filesystem#answer-842670).

Windows binaries will be at "sysroots\x86_64-pokysdk-mingw32\usr\bin\i586-poky-linux"

To use edison toolchain you have to provide it with sysroot option for compilation and linking, something like this:

```
"i586-poky-linux-g++.exe" --sysroot=../../../../core2-32-poky-linux
```

Comment: We are using the linaro toolchain at work with "VisualGDB" plugin for Visual Studio.  It's not the way I would have done it, but it works.

Comment: I didn't notice that you had answered your own question. Sort of. Although ELLCC can compile for both ARM and x86_64 Linux. With one download/set of tools.

Answer (score 1):

[ELLCC](http://ellcc.org) is available as a [binary download](http://ellcc.org/blog/?page_id=20295) for Windows, Linux, and Macs. It doesn't require cygwin, and can build Linux programs for several targets, including ARM. It is based on the clang/LLVM compiler.

Comment: I never used clang, so I didn't even try to google for it. Thank you, I will try it.