# Qt - How to deploy application dynamically on Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, deployment

I have an application that I built using Qt Creator on Linux and want to deploy it now. However, I don't want to statically build it as I don't want it to be open-sourced. I tried the `ldd ./YourExecutable` command, however that only lists (and not add) the additional dependencies the application needs in order for it to run. My question is, how do I gather the necessary dependencies without having to individually look for these files? Is there a tool, such as windeployqt.exe on Windows, that I can use on Linux for the same purpose? Or is there a better approach than the one I'm thinking of?

Comment: So, you want to compile it in a way that other people will not be able to read it without decompiling it?

Comment: Yes. On Windows, I'm able to create a folder, put the executable in it, and add all the necessary dependencies and files in order to make the executable work and have the folder be that as a release. I'm trying to do the same on Linux.

Comment: Would it work to have a tool that installs on Windows but compiles and links for Linux?

Comment: That could work too, however I'm not familiar with any tools that do this exact purpose?

Comment: I recommend you do more research before asking a question. This answer was easy to find:)

Answer (score 0):

1. Get Cygwin setup.exe: http://www.cygwin.com/

1.1. Run setup.exe and continue to package selection list.

1.2. Under Devel catagory select tools you need for compiling your source. For
     example 'GNU make'.

1.3. Finish installing.

2. Get linux crosscompilers for cygwin:
    "cygwin-gcc-linux.tar.bz2" (68.2 Mb).
    md5sum: 340e91a346f5bb17e660db10e43005b8

   These compilers are made with crosstool 0.28-rc37. This package contains:
    gcc-3.3.4 and gcc-2.95.3 for i386 (glibc 2.1.3) and gcc-3.3.3 for amd64 
    (glibc 2.3.2).

   Note! There is now newer version of GCC avaible with glibc 2.3.2: 
    "cygwin-gcc-3.3.6-glibc-2.3.2-linux.tar.bz2 (i386, x86_64)".

2.1. Copy 'cygwin-gcc-linux.tar.bz2' to 'c:\cygwin' or install directory which
     you selected in setup.exe.

2.2. Open Cygwin shell and change directory to root with 'cd /'.

2.3. Uncompress to Cygwin root with command: 
     'tar -jxvf cygwin-gcc-linux.tar.bz2'.

Cross-compilers are installed under '/opt/crosstool'. You can use theim 
 directly or with commands: gcc-linux, g++-linux, gcc-linux-2.95, 
 g++-linux-2.95, gcc-linux-x86_64 and g++-linux-x86_64.

From: [Cross-compiling on Windows for Linux](http://metamod-p.sourceforge.net/cross-compiling.on.windows.for.linux.html)
More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769968/c-cross-compiler-from-windows-to-linux).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to use the shared library deployment option:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/linux-deployment.html#creating-the-application-package

Then if you wanted to go further than that, you could look into making a .rpm or a .deb .

There are lots of examples of qt projects that are now available on GitHub and have packages made.  Usually for prebuilt binaries you need to make one for x86 and a separate one for x64.

Hope that helps.