# How to cross-platform compile on windows for linux using gcc?

Tags: python, c++, linux, gcc, cross-compiling

My aim is to create cross-platform C++ python modules.
I'm using`Cyther` (cross-platform The Cross-Platform Cython/Python Compiler).

Cyther uses `GCC` to compile modules and gives the user the ability to add GCC command-line args.

So, I need run compiler on Windows, but compile for Linux. What args I must pass to GCC to compile a module for Linux (or other platform)?

Is this possible, if so how?

Comment: Tried doing some prior research; like using your favorite search engine? And why so many tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gcc must be built separately for each compilation target. It can be built for any target on any host. The target you need is `i386-linux-gnu` (or often `i586-linux-gnu`) for 32-bit and `x86_64-linux-gnu` for 64-bit Linux.

Note that it provides separate binaries, `i386-linux-gnu-gcc`, `x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc` etc. Parameters are then the same.

I am not sure anybody provides that, but you can build it yourself. A tool to help you with that is described in [C++ cross-compiler from Windows to Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769968/c-cross-compiler-from-windows-to-linux).

Or you can go the simpler way and build on Linux (including cross-compilation to Windows). This kind of things is just so much easier on a decent Linux distribution.