# Get error when try to build Go code for Linux on Windows 10

Tags: linux, windows, go, cgo

I try to build Go code on Windows with `CGO_ENABLED=1`. I have a .bat file with

```
set GOOS=linux
set GOARCH=amd64
set CGO_CFLAGS=-g -O2 -w
set CGO_ENABLED=1
go build main.go constants.go functions.go
```

But I get error:

```
gcc_linux_amd64.c: In function '_cgo_sys_thread_start':
gcc_linux_amd64.c:62:2: error: unknown type name 'sigset_t'
  sigset_t ign, oset;
  ^
```

What should I do? I could't find such error anywhere.

P.S. If I haven't got "-w" flag in "CGO_CFLAGS" I will get this:

```
# runtime/cgo
_cgo_export.c:1:0: error: -fPIC ignored for target (all code is position 
independent) [-Werror]
 /* Created by cgo - DO NOT EDIT. */
 ^
cc1.exe: all warnings being treated as errors
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you need a cross compiler and the dev environment for compiling a C program for Linux. After searching around, this post may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4770417/3196456 .

Or, as you are using Windows 10, a more easier way is to try [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10), which can give you a whole Linux development experience on Windows. If your Windows build is greater than 16215, you can directly install one through Microsoft Store, for example, [Ubuntu](https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9NBLGGH4MSV6).

Comment: I decided to use Windows Subsystem for Linux. Thank you for advice!