# Executable for Linux while using Qt Creater on Windows 7

Tags: linux, qt, qt-creator, cross-compiling

I am new to Qt. I have developed simple GUI using Qt creator on windows 7. But now i want to use the same GUI on Linux. I have gone through internet but could not find satisfactory answer. I know that i have to use cross compiler. But i do not know which cross compiler to use and how to use it. So how to build an .exe for linux from windows 7 platform??

Regards,
Digvijay

Comment: The .exe is the binary for windows, you could run with wine in linux, but you can not use it directly, you should get a .elf cross-compiler, but I do not know a cross-compiler from windows for linux, I know what inverse that is mxe.

Comment: it's going to be easier to get a linux machine, install QT and just build your project there.

Comment: Concerning compile on Windows for Linux, I found [SO: C++ cross-compiler from Windows to Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4770417/7478597). How this can be configured properly in Qt/QtCreator, I've no idea... (I've no experience with Qt creator but I expect that it should be able to create portable C++ code. We explicitly have chosen Qt to be able to make portable GUI code.)

Comment: Look like i should build the project on Linux. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I would not recommend cross-compiling unless you have no choice, or the target HW is way too slow to compile. Just install QtCreator on Linux and build it there.