# How to Build the C code for linux target on windows platform/machine

Tags: linux, windows

I have a bundle of c files with `CMAKE` support. My requirement is to build the sources for `Linux target on windows platform/machine.` As of now, I do not have any compiler package. Is it possible to build for linux target from windows machine? Do we have any such compiler packages?
Can anyone suggest the procedure to achieve this!

Regards,
Anil Kumar. B

Answer (score 0):

Compiling at a system like Windows for another system like Linux is call cross compiling. See: [questions/4769968](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769968/c-cross-compiler-from-windows-to-linux)

Comment: My requirement is to build bundle of sources using gcc for the Linux target. so please guide me in this direction. I should be able to run the generated binary on linux target.

Comment: Do we have such support(to build for linux target) using gcc on windows.