# Linux docker build on Windows

Tags: c++, linux, windows, docker, build

I am developing a C++ application on a Linux virtual (ubuntu) machine hosted on Windows:

- build the project using CMake
- create .deb packages (they install docker containers on the Linux host, where my app runs)
- the docker containers use /usr/bin, /usr/conf, /etc ... directories on Linux

The problem is that, if I run cmake on Windows, then the directories are missing (/usr/bin, /etc ...)
Is it possible (and if yes, then how) to build the project on Windows, without the Linux VM ? (it is really slow and cumbersome)

For ex. can I create the necessary directories on Windows and run cmake, so that at least the build can be made on Windows, bypassing the VM ?

Comment: You need to cross compile, here few examples on how to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769968/c-cross-compiler-from-windows-to-linux

Answer (score 0):

Did you try WSL2?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-install

It would be faster than on VM.