# Prepare a shared object in Windows that will be used in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio, shared-libraries

I have a C# project that does a Dllimport of a dll file from a c++ code. The solution is made targetting .NET Core and the executable works fine in Windows.

I tried to publish the solution using linux-x64 as target runtime. I compiled the c++ code into an .so file that is included in the project files. However, when I try to execute the program in linux I get an error **Unable to load shared library**

If I run `file` onto the shared object I get:

```
shared_lib.so: PE32+ executable (DLL) (console) x86-64, for MS Windows
```

So maybe the problem is that the .so file is not correctly compiled for linux? I basically just took the same compilation lines and changed shared_lib.dll to shared_lib.so but I guess that was too naive. In particular I have:

```
g++ -c -DBUILD_MY_DLL shared_lib.cpp 
g++ -shared -o shared_lib.so shared_lib.o -Wl,--out-implib,libshared_lib.a
```

Is there some flag that one has to set in order to make the shared library available for linux?

Comment: ***I basically just took the same compilation lines and changed shared_lib.dll to shared_lib.so but I guess that was too naive.*** You can't just rename a windows binary to have the extension of a linux one. You need to build for linux.

Comment: This may help: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769968/c-cross-compiler-from-windows-to-linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769968/c-cross-compiler-from-windows-to-linux)